# Laravel localhost:8000 not staying alive and drops after loading in browser

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

I have posted this question on [as a two part question](http://laravel.io/forum/11-22-2014-notfoundhttpexception-and-php-artisan-serve-will-not-stay-up?page=1#reply-17386) while I was able to figure out the initial question by creating a route, the second part of the question is what I still have not figured out, which is why does localhost:8000 go down after I enter that into the url of the browser.

When I go to the terminal and type "php artisan serve", then the following line appears and that is great:

```
Tariks-Mac-mini:112214_blog tam3$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
```

However, when I go to the browser and type in localhost:8000, then as soon as I hit the enter/return key, then the following appears in the terminal:

```
Tariks-Mac-mini:112214_blog tam3$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
Tariks-Mac-mini:112214_blog tam3$
```

It returns to the blinking cursor.

Now, in the browser, initially I find the "You have arrived" page, but if I reload the page, then I receive that find localhost:8000 message.

Why can't the server stay alive?

Comment: How does your routes.php look? And which URL are you typing into the browser?

Comment: Just localhost:8000 and my routes are set to the default / I create a laravel new 112214_blog and I did not change anything from there

Comment: So it's a totally clean install?

Comment: Yes, completely clean install. I asked this same question on laravel, is my MAMP effecting this in any way - should I place the mcrypt directory within the Sites folder?

Comment: Here's the laravel.log production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /Users/tam3/mcrypt/laravel-master/your-dir/112214_blog/bootstrap/compiled.php:5682
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/tam3/mcrypt/laravel-master/your-dir/112214_blog/bootstrap/compiled.php(5006): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /Users/tam3/mcrypt/laravel-master/your-dir/112214_blog/server.php(19): require_once('/Users/tam3/mcr...')
#12 {main} [] []

Comment: what your laravel version?

Comment: MAMP is living outside that environment, so you'll be just fine. I'm wondering what would happen if you try to visit localhost:8000/index.php and see if that works when refreshing. And yes, as xjaphx says, What's your laravel version? Also, try to do a php -v too check your PHP version.

Comment: Laravel 4 and I it had to do with everything pointing to MAMP. I did the following to update - curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6, followed by export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH, then re-running the ./configure, make, make install - except when I did that within the /php-5.6/ext/mcrypt make install -prefix /usr/local/php5/bin - now the server is running with no issues - scratch that one issue - had to run php artisan key:generate and place key within my app/config/app.php file - I have arrived :-)

Comment: Glad to hear! Try to look into homebrew and/or Laravel Homestead - that way you're pretty much done dealing with makes, builds and all that.